# Differentiating streams in combined stdout and stderr

Tags: java, bash, stdout, processbuilder, stderr

When I normally spawn a new process using ProcessBuilder, I know that I can get the stdout and stderr separately by getting the respective streams and waiting for the process to complete. In some cases, this hangs.

I decided that I want to combine my two streams to avoid this issue.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder().command(parsedCommand);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process proc = builder.start();
String out = MyStringBuilder.getStreamOutput(proc.getInputStream());
proc.waitFor();
```

I'm not sure how to recognize each of the streams. When I check the stderr of some bash commands (e.g., "ls *.fakefile") by redirecting the output to a file, the output look the same as what I would get in stdout.

Is there normally some way I can differentiate the streams inside of the single output?

Comment: *Is there normally some way I can differentiate the streams inside of the single output?* No. That's why they're two outputs.

Comment: *In some cases, this hangs* It sounds like the hanging should be solved in a different way. Can you tell us more about the situation that produces hanging?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I thought there may have been some way for me to map my own information onto each line that is being redirected.

Comment: @Joni I think this question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806651/java-process-waitfor-and-readline-hangs

I'm going to continue with the option of redirecting my stderr (vs. creating different threads for each output), because I know what to look for during an error state.